# Python maximum recursion depth exceeded when installing a module

Tags: python, boto, python-module, python-install

I got maximum recursion depth exceeded when installing `gcs-oauth2-boto-plugin-1.4` on my mac. I downloaded and unzipped the package, ran `sudo python setup.py install` under the installation directory, pretty standard stuff that you would do when install a Python module. I was doing it in a virtual environment (virtualenv). I did not encounter any problem while installing it on the original environment. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Edit: I got the same error when trying to install it with `pip install gcs-oauth2-boto-plugin==1.4`

Comment: It worked for me. Could you please share some details like OS, stacktrace ets?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It is a good possibility that there is some bug in source code that is causing infinite loop and recursion limit error. Still, standard recursion limit in python is quite low (2000 I guess), which might cause problems in some cases. Increasing the recursion limit might work.

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)
```

Add this line to install.py of your source code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But I still get the same error. The weird thing is that it works perfect on my original environment. It only produces such error in the virtualenv.

Comment: I am also facing the error when i use different environment. please someone suggest an answer?